# Make winston logger variable accessible to all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I am writing a node js tool which consists of many node js scripts. For logging, I am using winston. But I am facing one problem. Firstly, I made a separate JS file which has a function of creating logger and clearing logger transports and it looks something as below:-

```
'use strict';

var winston = require('winston');
var logger;

function createLogger(service) {
    logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        level: 'info',
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.File(
                {filename: ('logs/' + service + '_error.log'),
                json: false})
        ]
    });

    return logger;
}

function clearLogger() {
    logger.clear()
}

module.exports = {
    createLogger: createLogger,
    clearLogger: clearLogger,
    logger: logger
};
```

Lets call above file as logger-handler.js. Now, initially from say, A.js, I called createLogger function with some service name. It got instantiated and I can use it in A.js. A.js calls some functions in say, B.js also. Now, if I wanted to use same logger in B.js, I am getting error that logger is undefined. To use in B.js, I did something as follows:-

```
var logger = require('./logger-handler').logger;
```

I thought it should work because logger is global variable and I have initialized it before coming to B.js. But it is assigning logger variable as undefined.

Can someone help in what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post A.js? It really seems like you might have imported b before instantiation. Also I dont see why you would need to expose `createLogger`, why not just instantiate the logger immediately and expose the `logger` and `clearLogger`

Answer (score 2):

your logger is **NOT** a global variable, he is only exist in A.js.
if you want to make the logger a global variable- you have to do specifically by assign it to the `global` variable  like so:

```
global.logger = logger;
```

---

### Note:

it's good practice to assign a prefix for every global variable so you will know that is a global one. i'm using __ as prefix (double low dash)

Answer (score -1):

Yep! your logger is undefined because in that module all you did was declaring it as var and never created a logger before calling it like that:

```
var logger = require('./logger-handler').logger;
```

You need to initialize it first before calling it so something like that would work:

```
import {createLogger, logger} from './logger-handler';

//init your logger with the service name - based on whatever you wrote, so not too sure -
createLogger("enter the service");

//now your logger is ready to be used
logger.log('info', 'all done');
```

Also, your createlogger function does not need to return a logger.